# Realloc creates dangling pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers

I wrote some array code that allocates memory and each value in the array is a type. I then have another array that consists of in to the first array for references.

Both arrays can grow. It uses realloc. Because the 2nd array contains pointers in to the first, they are surely not updated when the first array changes(I don't do it manually and there is no GC). Surely all the pointers in the 2nd array are invalid! (they point to memory that was free'ed by realloc).

1. This is the case right?
2. This seems like it would make persistent pointers to blocks of memory that may move very dangerous?
3. What is the standard solution? Don't use "global" pointers? Using pointers to pointers to pointers? I think I could make the 2nd array use **'s and could probably get things to work.
4. In a MT environment, things are even worse. Local pointers access may be moved in the middle, then the memory changed, and the local pointer is now wrong. (Which, of course might be solved by preventing the moves by lock, etc...)
5. Go with functional programming?

Comment: 1. I think you have a problem with the data structure. 2. Why are you using pointers? Smart pointers perhaps.

Comment: Don't store pointers to the first array then. Store indices. Those will stay valid if your first array only keeps growing.

Comment: @PSkocik Yes, But that isn't always the solution. That works in this case because I'm using an indexable array. It doesn't answer the question, only tries to provide a specific solution(a solution I already though about and when I first wrote the code that was my initial response.. But I was like "Hey, int's and void* takes up the same space, why not just use a pointer!"... then quickly realizing that was a bad idea.

Comment: @AbstractDissonance [MCVE] or it didn't happen.

Comment: It pretty much is. If you want to refer to a growing container, you need references that won't get invalidated as the referenced container grows. If it's an array, you can use indices, if it's a map, you can use keys. If there's no such thing, you can introduce, at a performance cost, another layer of indirection and have the both containers store pointers or smart pointers to actual objects that will never ever move. Another option is to forget about sharing (especially a good idea if you're in a MT environment) and have the second container create its own copies.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the realloc can invalidate your references. If there is no continuous space for relocating your array will be moved.
Consider using a container as the std::deque.

Comment: Just for the record, standard container references (i.e. iterators) will also be invalidated using operations that change the containers' size.

Comment: For a std::vector and some other containers that is true. But a std::deque just invalidates references for linear insertion. push_back and push_front doesn't invalidate its iterators. See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque

Answer (score 1):

> 1) This is the case right?

Yes.

> 2) This seems like it would make persistent pointers to blocks of memory that may move very dangerous?

Yes.

> 3) What is the standard solution?

You design your application such that the life-times of your objects is well defined so that you do not refer to them after they are no longer required.

> 4) In a MT environment, things are even worse. Local pointers access may be moved in the middle, then the memory changed, and the local pointer is now wrong. (Which, of course might be solved by preventing the moves by lock, etc...)

Obviously you should never use a pointer that no-longer pointers to its resource. Managing shared resources in a MT environment is non trivial and there are a whole bunch of tools and techniques to achieve it.

> 5) Go with functional programming?

It is always advisable to avoid pointers if you can.

Without a specific problem it is hard to give a specific solution. But in order to achieve "not pointing at disappeared resources" we have various tools to employ. We have *smart pointers*, we have *containers* and we have *value semantics*. We need to understand how to use all of those but also we need to *design* with object *lifetime* in mind as a **major** consideration.

Object life-time should *always* be an important factor. However some languages (like Java for instance) mitigate against bad-design by providing a "safer" environment. `C++`, on the other hand, is rather less forgiving. However it does have a whole bunch of sophisticated tools for the task. That means a steeper learning curve but more efficiency and better control.